# Ng-class based on value returned from controller

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, html, ionic-framework

I have tried to set icon style based on value returned from controller,the console log showing the value triggered correctly but it seems i have an issue with Ng-class expression. Any help on this is very much appreciated. Thanks in advance .

**controller code**

```js
$scope.class = "favorite_border";
    $scope.changeClass = function(){
    if ($scope.class === "favorite_border")
        $scope.class = "favorite";
     else
        $scope.class = "favorite_border";
      console.log($scope.class);
    }
```

**view code**

```html
<i ion-ripple ion-ripple-color="#ff0000"class="material-icons" style="font-size: 32px" ng-click="changeClass()" ng-class="'{{class}}'== favorite_border ? 'favorite_border' : 'favorite'"> {{class}}</i>
```

**CSS style**

```js
.favorite_border{ color:gray};.favorite{color:red};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use expression while evaluation condition, change it as,

```
<i ion-ripple ion-ripple-color="#ff0000"class="material-icons" style="font-size: 32px" ng-click="changeClass()" ng-class="class === 'favorite_border' ? 'favorite_border' : 'favorite'"> {{class}}</i>
```

**DEMO**

```css
.favorite_border{ color:yellow};.favorite{color:red};
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  
<body>
  <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">

    <i ion-ripple ion-ripple-color="#ff0000"class="material-icons" style="font-size: 32px" ng-click="changeClass()" ng-class="class == 'favorite_border' ? 'favorite_border' : 'favorite'"> {{class}}</i>
  </div>


  <!-- Angular Material Dependencies -->
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.6/angular.js"></script>
<script>
    var app = angular.module('app', []);

    app.controller("ctrl", function($scope) {
       $scope.class = "favorite_border";
      $scope.changeClass = function(){
      if ($scope.class === "favorite_border")
        $scope.class = "favorite";
     else
        $scope.class = "favorite_border";
      console.log($scope.class);
     }
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The issue solved but this lead me to another challenge , the <i> tag actually within a <div> which is basically inside <ng - repeat > , when i click on one icon all icons in the view triggered and changed , how can i solve it . many thank to all again.

Comment: you might need to generate an #name and apply the class wih the dynamically generated name

Comment: sorry , can you explain more if it is possible.

Comment: i think i need to give each <i> an id in the first load of ng-repeat and then when click i have to pass this id along with .

Comment: I made it work i have changed the <i> tag as   `<i ion-ripple ion-ripple-color="#ff0000"class="material-icons" style="font-size: 32px"    ng-click="PassSelectedIndex({{$index}}) ;" ng-class="{{$index}} ===selected ? class='favorite' : class='favorite_border'"> 
                  {{class}} 
                  </i>  
` and in the controller i received the index and return it back to the view , the only glitch i have now , i am not able to keep  previous clicked icons status , the icons lost their class , @st2rseeker,@Samar Rizvi

Answer (score 2):

Set your view like this:

```
<i ion-ripple ion-ripple-color="#ff0000"class="material-icons" style="font-size: 32px" ng-click="changeClass()" ng-class="class === 'favorite_border' ? 'favorite_border' : 'favorite'"> {{class}}</i>
```

or based on your controller code above:

```
<i ion-ripple ion-ripple-color="#ff0000"class="material-icons" style="font-size: 32px" ng-click="changeClass()" ng-class="class"> {{class}}</i>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change it to

```
ng-class="class == 'favorite_border' ? 'favorite_border' : 'favorite'"
```

or even

```
ng-class="class"
```

Just remember to initialize `$scope.class='...'` with the appropriate initial class you want.

**Exaplanation:**

The expression in the `ng-class` will be evaluated as more or less expression in JS - with variables being prefixed with `$scope`. Therefore, if we look at your expression:

```
'{{class}}'== favorite_border ? 'favorite_border' : 'favorite'
```

it will be interpreted as:

```
'{{$scope.class}}'== $scope.favorite_border ? 'favorite_border' : 'favorite'
```

which in turn will be inferred as:

```
''== $scope.favorite_border ? 'favorite_border' : 'favorite'
```

initially, until you toggle the class, and

```
'favorite_border'== $scope.favorite_border ? 'favorite_border' : 'favorite'
```

None of them make sense in the context (first and second will be `false ? 'favorite_border' : 'favorite'` ==> `'favorite'`) and will not evaluate to an intended class name.